# CSS grid-template-areas not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.content {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 4px solid lime;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a d'
    'b d'
    'c d';
}

textarea, iframe {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content > .a {grid-area: "a";}
.content > .b {grid-area: "b";}
.content > .c {grid-area: "c";}
.content > .d {grid-area: "d"; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <textarea class="a">a</textarea>
  <textarea class="b">b</textarea>
  <textarea class="c">c</textarea>
  <iframe class="d"></iframe>
</div>
```

I expected the grid to look like this:

```
a d
b d
c d
```

but instead, as can be seen above, it ends up looking like this:

```
a b
c d
c d
. .
```

**What am i doing wrong?**

Adding

```
grid-template-rows: 3;
grid-template-columns: 2;
```

also didn't help.

Comment: remove the quotes from grid-area

Comment: Thanks Temani, that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

using the snippet below might help.

```
.content {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a d"
    "b d"
    "c d"
}
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't fix it

Comment: @FireFuro99 please see [link](https://codepen.io/Anurella/pen/BadvVEd)